# Google Cloud clustered table not working?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bigdata

On google cloud, I've created an ingestion-time partitioned table clustered on columns `Hour`, `Minute` and `Second`. From my knowledge on clustered table, this means that my rows are distributed in clusters organized by hour, each **hour cluster** contains **minute clusters** and each minute cluster should contain **second clusters**.

So I would expect that when I query data from 13:10:00 to 13:10:30, the query should affect only rows inside cluster of hour 13, minute 30 and seconds from 0 to 30. Am I wrong?

I'm asking this, because actually it seems clusters are not working on my project, since I have a test table of 140 MB, but when I add **WHERE** condition on my clustered columns, BigQuery still says the query will affect all the table size, while I would expect that using clustered columns in Where condition, the amount of data queried should be smaller. Any help? Thank you.

Comment: have you actually tried to run it? were it actually billed you with 140MB? Dry Run provides estimation for clustered tables on at worst case - but not actual cost that can be identified only after query actually run

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant What do you mean with "run it"? If you mean the query, yes, I ran it. Is it possible that clusters work only with larger amount of data?

Comment: yes and yes for both

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant ok, thank you so much. Currently I'm using a development account, I'll push fake data in the table and I'll verify.

Comment: another factor to consider here is fragmentation - if your table get constantly updated  - clusters become fragmented and less cost effective. BigQuery engine has some logic to optimize your data time by time, but it is recommended to re-materialize your data by yourself if you feel that clustering is getting too fragmented and you dont see cost effectiveness. but still size is factor too

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I get it, thank you

Comment: This is a really good post that might help you understand partitioning/clustering in some more detail. https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-optimized-cluster-your-tables-65e2f684594b